# Disable modal button Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Не получается заблокировать Bootstrap кнопку. Визуально она показывается заблокированной, но при клике всё равно открывается модальное окно.

Код кнопки:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger disabled" type="button" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteGroup">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </button>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `button` надо писать `disabled="disabled"`, класс `.disabled` для тегов `a` стилизованных под кнопку.

```
<button disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-danger disabled" type="button" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteGroup">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</button>
```